# Check if a given character is whitespace

Tags: bash

In my script I take a string, loop through each character and pass it into a function which uses a switch case to check what character it is and act accordingly. It works fine, but it doesnt seem to be able to match whitespace characters. What notation can I use?

NOTE: Only a single character will be passed into this function, so I only need to figure out if this single character is a whitespace character.

Snippet from the code

```
    " ")
        doSomething
        ;;
    "a")
        doSomethingElse
        ;;
    "b")
        doSomethingElse
        ;;
    "c")
        doSomethingElse
        ;;
```

Also tried

```
    *\ * )
        tap 388 1127
        ;;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your first example tests for exactly one space, your seconds tests for a space anywhere (possibly surrounded by other characters), depends on what you want?

Answer (score 12):

In BASH, you can use POSIX [character classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) to match whitespace with `[[:space:]]`.

```
case $var in
    [[:space:]])
        doSomething
        ;;
esac
```

The `[[:space:]]` will match any whitespace character.

Testing for character classes can also be done inside double brackets:

```
[[ $var == [[:space:]] ]] && doSomething
```

Comment: +1, It's worth noting that this will match all whitespace (tab, newline etc) chars not only just a single space.

Comment: This is inaccurate, what you are doing is testing only a single `whitespace` character. Also, you should quote `$var` in the case statement.

Comment: I cant find where my answer is inaccurate.  `$var` actually does not need to be in quotes in the `case` statement.

Comment: @JohnB Your case statement tests for exactly one occurrence of a whitespace character, not multiple as you're implying.

Comment: @JohnB I'm saying it will match only a single occurance. Unless I'm misinterpreting what you're saying, you're clearly implying the opposite "I don't know of a way to test only a single space using case in BASH but you can get around this by using if statements" (but your case example already is matching only a single space)

Comment: @JohnB Feel like we're running in circles, if you replace `[[:space:]]` with `" "` in your [tag:case] statement it will match EXACTLY the same cases as your first [tag:if] statement.

Comment: @BroSlow I was talking about the `case` statement the OP used, not my solution.

Comment: @JohnB ok, now it's accurate. Changing -1 to +1 (also removed my answer based on op's note about only testing for single [[:space:]])